# Parsing HTML with URLlib - How to print more than 1 of each tag?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm writing a program to parse webpages to snatch the title and headers so I can give SEO consultation without manually clicking through all the code.

The code works, but only returns a single instance of each tag I'm looking for. If there are, say, 5 h1's in the HTML, I only get the first one. How do I get the rest? I'm thinking a loop but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Here's the code:

```
# import libraries
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#specify URL
quote_page = input('What URL would you like to scrape?')

#query website and return HTML to the variable page
page = urlopen(quote_page)

#parse the HTML with BeautifulSoup and store in variable 'soup'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

#now we have the HTML as soup, so we need to grab the title and headers

title = soup.find('title')
h1s = soup.find('h1')
h2s = soup.find('h2')
h3s = soup.find('h3')
metadescription = soup.find('meta name="description"')


#print out the data in readable format, including "none" for missing data 
#types
print()
print('Title:')
print(title)
print()
print('H1s:')
print(h1s)
print()
print('H2s:')
print(h2s)
print()
print('H3s:')
print(h3s)
print()
print('Description:')
print(metadescription)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `soup.find_all('h1')` to get them all.